# How can I extract heartbeat from PPG raw data with a frequency of 100Hz on Android?

Tags: java, android

I got ppg raw data is [930906,930037,929210,928572,928038,927572,927296,927042,926946,926880,926899,926931,927013,927092,927289,927449,927689,927890,928079,928321,928449,928584,928604,928656,928618,928498,928430,928328,928152,927996,927824,927740,927652,927593,927541,927635,927691,927710,927860,927207,927761,928315,928594,928790,929018,929232,929486,929779,930014,930289,930524,930753,930993,931314,931542,931761,932055,932395,932642,932925,933162,933289,933224,933058,932596,932071,931334,930549,929613,928660,927823,926985,926271,925704,925159,924817,924619,924493,924419,924427,924486,924599,924674,924878,925072,925228,925513,925755,926008,926263,926360,926557,926680,926772,926831,926800,926706,926659,926538,926506] ,100Hz  how can i get the hearbeat?

search result try gpt